# Selecting a random value from a dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, random

Here is my function:

```
def evilSetup():
    words = setUp()
    result = {}
    char = input('Please enter your one letter guess: ')
    for word in words:
        key = ' '.join(char if c == char else '-' for c in word)
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = []
        result[key].append(word)
    return max(result.items(), key=lambda keyValue: len(keyValue[1]))

from collections import defaultdict
import random
words= evilSetup()#list of words from which to choose
won, lost = 0,0 #accumulators for games won, and lost
while True:
    wrongs=0 # accumulator for wrong guesses
    secretWord = words
    print(secretWord) #for testing purposes
    guess= len(secretWord)*'_'
    print('Secret Word:' + ' '.join(guess))
    while wrongs < 8 and guess != secretWord:
        wrongs, guess = playRound(wrongs, guess)
    won, lost = endRound(wrongs,won,lost)
    if askIfMore()== 'N':
            break
printStats(won, lost)
```

The function will take a list of words, and sort them into a dictionary based on the position of the guessed letter. As of now, it returns the key,value pair that is the largest. What I would like it to ultimately return is a random word from the biggest dictionary entry. The values as of now are in the form of a list.

For example {- - -, ['aah', 'aal', 'aas']}

Ideally I would grab a random word from this list to return. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list `lst`, then you can simply do:

```
random_word = random.choice(lst)
```

to get a random entry of the list. So here, you will want something like:

```
return random.choice(max(result.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[1]))[1])
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                              ^^^^
```

Comment: Yes, but the list is currently stored as a dictionary value. Wouldn't I have to separate it from the dictionary first in order to use this?

Comment: Clarified my answer; instead of returning one item from the dictionary (which is a tuple of length 2), you instead call `random.choice` on the `[1]` entry of that item and return the result of that.

Comment: I actually have another question regarding this. I edited my main post to include main code that I am working with. Instead of enacting the random in the evilSetup() function, how can I use it properly to store the random word in the variable secret word? I was thinking something like secretWord = random.choice(words) but that will seemingly just pass the whole dictionary.

Comment: @Droxbot It would be preferable for you to ask your new question as a separate question.